# Posting JSON with Curl to a rails server gives ParseError -795

Tags: json, curl, rails-api

Posting the below gives a MultiJson::ParseError - 795: unexpected token at '{"investor": {"name": "Theresa Enyedi"}'

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/investors -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"investor": {"name": "Theresa Enyedi"}}'
```

Help would be appreciated.

Mahalo
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-d '{json_data":` should be `-d '{"json_data":`

by the way, -XPOST is not necessary, since you offer -d argument

Comment: Thank you. Stupid typo and I looked at it over and over.